# How to handle getItemViewType with 3 different views types

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-viewholder

Basically, I have a recyclerview that should populate data coming from server, there is 3 types of items (photos, videos, essays) I did everything correctly and it shows normally but once I start scrolling it crashed with this error:

```
   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
```

The arrays are not empty, the array size of photo = 2 , videos = 1 and essay = 1.
I'm sure the error is caused by `getItemViewType` method, I really can't get the idea behind it, I've read some definitions on its role but still can handle this time!

I just want all items from all arrays to in one recycler in order!

**Adapter:**

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

  final int VIEW_TYPE_PHOTO = 0;
  final int VIEW_TYPE_VIDEO = 1;
  final int VIEW_TYPE_ESSAY = 2;

  public GalleryAdapter(ArrayList<Gallery.Photo> photo, ArrayList<Gallery.Vedio> video,
      ArrayList<Gallery.Essay> essay, Context context) {
    this.photo = photo;
    this.video = video;
    this.essay = essay;
    this.context = context;
  }

  ArrayList<Gallery.Photo> photo;
  ArrayList<Gallery.Vedio> video;
  ArrayList<Gallery.Essay> essay;
  Context context;


  @Override
  public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    // for photos and videos
    View itemLayoutView1 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
        R.layout.gallery_item1, parent, false);

   // for essay
    View itemLayoutView2 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
        R.layout.gallery_item2, parent, false);

    switch (viewType) {

      case VIEW_TYPE_PHOTO:

        PhotoViewHolder photoholder = new PhotoViewHolder(itemLayoutView1);
        return photoholder;

      case VIEW_TYPE_VIDEO:

        VideoViewHolder videoholder = new VideoViewHolder(itemLayoutView1);
        return videoholder;

      case VIEW_TYPE_ESSAY:

        EssayViewHolder essayholder = new EssayViewHolder(itemLayoutView2);
        return essayholder;

      default:
        return null;
    }


  }

  public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 3;
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    // return 0; // I tried this line only and still caused the same crash

   // causes the same crash
    switch (position) {
      case 0:
        return VIEW_TYPE_PHOTO;
      case 1:
        return VIEW_TYPE_VIDEO;
      case 2:
        return VIEW_TYPE_ESSAY;
      default:
        return -1;
      }
  }


  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


    if (holder instanceof PhotoViewHolder) {
      ((PhotoViewHolder) holder).pupulatePhoto(photo.get(position));
    }

     if (holder instanceof VideoViewHolder) {
      ((VideoViewHolder) holder).pupulateVideo(video.get(position));
    }

    if (holder instanceof EssayViewHolder) {
      ((EssayViewHolder) holder).pupulateEssay(essay.get(position));
    }


  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return photo.size() + video.size() + essay.size();
  }

  public class PhotoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView title;
    private TextView counter;
    private TextView dummy;
    private ImageView itemPic;
    private ImageView eassyCover;

    public PhotoViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);

      title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
      counter = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.counter);
      dummy = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dummy_txt);
      itemPic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_pic);
      eassyCover = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.essay_cover);
    }


    public void pupulatePhoto(Gallery.Photo photo) {
      title.setText("Photo " + photo.getTitle());
      Picasso.with(context).load(photo.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.bg_blur).into(itemPic);
    }
  }

  public class VideoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    private TextView title;
    private TextView counter;
    private TextView dummy;
    private ImageView itemPic;
    private ImageView eassyCover;

    public VideoViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);

      title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
      counter = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.counter);
      dummy = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dummy_txt);
      itemPic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_pic);
      eassyCover = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.essay_cover);
    }

    public void pupulateVideo(Gallery.Vedio video) {
      title.setText("Video " + video.getTitle());
      Picasso.with(context).load(video.getPreviewImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.bg_blur)
          .into(itemPic);
    }

  }

  public class EssayViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    private TextView title;
    private TextView counter;
    private TextView dummy;
    private ImageView itemPic;
    private ImageView eassyCover;

    public EssayViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);

      title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
      counter = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.counter);
      dummy = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dummy_txt);
      itemPic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_pic);
      eassyCover = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.essay_cover);
    }

    public void pupulateEssay(Gallery.Essay essay) {
      title.setText("Essay " + essay.getTitle());
    }
  }

}
```

---

**Update #1**

The new Code for the adapter when I tried combining all the three together:

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

  final int VIEW_TYPE_PHOTO = 0;
  final int VIEW_TYPE_VIDEO = 1;
  final int VIEW_TYPE_ESSAY = 2;

  ArrayList<Object> objects;
  Context context;

  public GalleryAdapter(ArrayList<Object> objects, Context context) {
    this.objects = objects;
    this.context = context;
  }

  @Override
  public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.gallery_item2, parent, false);

    switch (viewType) {

      case VIEW_TYPE_PHOTO:
        PhotoViewHolder photoholder = new PhotoViewHolder(view);
        return photoholder;

      case VIEW_TYPE_VIDEO:
        VideoViewHolder videoholder = new VideoViewHolder(view);
        return videoholder;

      case VIEW_TYPE_ESSAY:
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.gallery_item, parent, false);

        EssayViewHolder essayholder = new EssayViewHolder(view);
        return essayholder;

      default:
        return null;
    }

  }

  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {

//Gallery.Photo and Gallery.Vedio are the models
    if (objects.get(position) instanceof Gallery.Photo) {
      return VIEW_TYPE_PHOTO;
    } else if (objects.get(position) instanceof Gallery.Vedio) {
      return VIEW_TYPE_VIDEO;
    } else {
      return VIEW_TYPE_ESSAY;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    if (getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_TYPE_PHOTO) {


          // gives me NPE !
//      ((PhotoViewHolder) holder).pupulatePhoto(objects.get(position));


    } else if (getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_TYPE_VIDEO) {


    } else {


    }


  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return objects.size();
  }

  public class PhotoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    private TextView title;
    private TextView counter;
    private TextView dummy;
    private ImageView itemPic;
    private ImageView eassyCover;

    public PhotoViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);

      title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
      counter = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.counter);
      dummy = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dummy_txt);
      itemPic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_pic);
      eassyCover = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.essay_cover);
    }

    public void pupulatePhoto(Gallery.Photo photo) {
      title.setText("Photo " + photo.getTitle());
Picasso.with(context).load(photo.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.bg_blur).into(itemPic);
    }
  }

  public class VideoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    private TextView title;
    private TextView counter;
    private TextView dummy;
    private ImageView itemPic;
    private ImageView eassyCover;

    public VideoViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);

      title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
      counter = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.counter);
      dummy = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dummy_txt);
      itemPic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_pic);
      eassyCover = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.essay_cover);
    }

    public void pupulateVideo(Gallery.Vedio video) {

      title.setText("Video " + video.getTitle());   Picasso.with(context).load(video.getPreviewImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.bg_blur)
          .into(itemPic);
    }

  }

  public class EssayViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    private TextView title;
    private TextView counter;
    private TextView dummy;
    private ImageView itemPic;
    private ImageView eassyCover;

    public EssayViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);

      title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
      counter = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.counter);
      dummy = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dummy_txt);
      itemPic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_pic);
      eassyCover = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.essay_cover);
    }

    public void pupulateEssay(Gallery.Essay essay) {
      title.setText("Essay " + essay.getTitle());
    }
  }


}
```

It works great, but I can't get the positions of the items correctly? When I call this method to populate the data and bind it withe view... it crashes and gives me NPE ?

```
   ((PhotoViewHolder) holder).pupulatePhoto(objects.get(position));
```

But it gives me an NPE !? every time I to use the position it crashes.! What did I miss!?

---

---

**Update #2**

I solved it, I forgot to cast the model arraylist '_' so I changed this

```
   ((PhotoViewHolder) holder).pupulatePhoto(objects.get(position));
```

to this

```
    ((PhotoViewHolder) holder).pupulatePhoto( (Gallery.Photo) objects.get(position));
```

now it works :D

Thanks a lot guys.!

Comment: "I just want all items from all arrays to in one recycler in order!" -- there is no order. What is the order? Instead of having a single collection of model data, you have three (`photo`, `video`, `essay`). You have not specified how those three are supposed to be combined to create a single `ReyclerView`. That not only impacts your `getItemViewType()` method, but also your `onBindViewHolder()` method, as you will crash there as well.

Comment: Maybe with this library it'll be easier for you to achieve what you want https://github.com/afollestad/sectioned-recyclerview

Comment: @CommonsWare ok i get what you mean, what if I combined all data from the three arrays into one array respectively, this way I can get the type and it would be in order.! right?

Comment: That is one possibility. Your `getItemViewType()` would look in the combined list, see what the model object is, and return a view type based upon it. And `onBindViewHolder()` would obtain the model object from the combined list. You could also keep the lists separate, but then teach `getItemViewType()` and `onBindViewHolder()` to consider the position as being across the combination of all three lists. Or, you could try [this library](https://github.com/martijnvdwoude/recycler-view-merge-adapter) and have three `RecylerView.Adapter` classes.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, I'll try that and see..

Comment: @CommonsWare can you help with new problem, see Update#1 please.

Comment: Which is the null object: `holder`, `objects` or something in the `pupulatePhoto` method, e.g. `photo.getTitle()`?

Comment: It's okay I found a solution,, I forget to cast to the model.! see update#2, thanks a lot guys.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in my case was to combine all the three array list into one from type Object and instantiates with the adapter constructor and then check the current position using `instanceof` with corresponding model.

```
@Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {

//Gallery.Photo and Gallery.Vedio are the models
    if (objects.get(position) instanceof Gallery.Photo) {
      return VIEW_TYPE_PHOTO;
    } else if (objects.get(position) instanceof Gallery.Vedio) {
      return VIEW_TYPE_VIDEO;
    } else {
      return VIEW_TYPE_ESSAY;
    }
  }
```

see Update#1 and #2 for full details.